# What preposition to use when referencing the subject of the survey/research?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I want to know the most common preposition used to reference the subject of *the survey/research.*

If the subject (of *research* or *a/the survey*) is "20,000 adults in Britain", then what **preposition** do we use to reference them?

For example, in this sentence,

> Researchers analyzed survey results ***from*** 20,000 British adults and found that those who exercised for 20 minutes each day were 40% less likely to suffer from significant levels of stress and anxiety.

Here the writer used the preposition **from** to reference the subject *20,000 British adults*, and I am curious about the **proper preposition** when I indicate the subject of the survey or research like this.

Answer (score 3):

> Doctors analyzed the **blood** *of|from* 500 patients.
>
> Researchers studied the **reaction speed** *of* 500 test subjects.
>
> Psychologists studied **drawings** *by* 500 kindergartners.
>
> Epidemiologists studied the **organism** *in* 500 infected persons.
>
> Immunologists studied the **effects** of the vaccine *on* 500 subjects.

The preposition will depend on the noun in boldface.  The preposition indicates the relationship of that noun to the object of the preposition.

Comment: Although I'm sure ***from*** is idiomatically far more common in OP's exact context, I can't see that ***of*** is in any way "incorrect".

Comment: Either would be OK.  My main point is that before you can decide on the preposition, you have to understand the relationship of the noun in the bolded position to the noun that is the object of the preposition.

Comment: Indeed. I wouldn't have a problem using ***with*** in your second and last examples (particularly with ***test** subjects* as the referent). As you say, it's more important (or at least, *just as important*) what "primary" noun (as highlighted by you) is involved, as opposed to the "secondary" noun following the preposition.